Regression spline for time to allow for slope changes
Suppose we have a regression / survival model where we would like to model follow-up time using a regression spline. Follow-up time has two phases (first treatment active, and second treatment completed i.e. not active) which we would like to consider i.e. allow for slope changes. However, the time points at which these phases occur can differ by subject (person). How can we construct the spline for time so that the slope can change as the subject passes from the first to second phase? Do we need to place a knot at this boundary but allow it to vary by subject?
Update (further details as requested)
I was wondering if this approach is possible to use in regression / survival models in general. Hence I just used the unit of person.
However, the current study for which I would like to consider this approach is a longitudinal study modeling counts (rates) over time. We have monthly  counts by sex for several months before start of intervention (I.e. baseline), during intervention (i.e. active phase),  and after intervention (i.e. post phase), in paired control and treatment sites. I had planned to use mean (since we have several months worth-) of “before” as baseline covariate as per ANCOVA approach. So the model will look roughly like:
Post = offset + baseline + month + sex + treatment + phase + time_since_start_active + time_since_start_post + (1|pair/clinic)
Where:
month is categorical to adjust for natural monthly changes,
treatment is yes/no indicating whether site is real intervention or control, phase is active/post.
The time terms are numeric which I would like to model with splines.
The terms in brackets are random effects.
The timeline is the same within but not between pairs of clinics. In other words, the lengths of active and post phases might differ between pairs of clinics. That’s why I was considering two time variables that I wondered if these could be constructed together in one spline term?
I am also aware of the need for interaction terms in the above model. In particular, I think there is a need to include random slopes for time variables since duration of phase might alter its slope?

If the two phases are well defined, might it be possible to rescale time for each individual to represent the fraction of the phase that has passed until that time?

@EdM, if we rescale time to a fraction, the phase change does not always occur at e.g. time = 0.5. Rather, second phase can occur at several times e.g. 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, depending on subject

I was thinking of trying to do something along the lines of what is described at the end of this web post https://rpubs.com/alecri/review_longitudinal where it talks about linear splines. It describes using 2 time variables, time and timepost, though the resulting curve is not smooth which I would like

Please edit the question to say more about what you are trying to model and the types of predictor variables involved. In a survival model the time-to-event or follow-up time is typically the outcome variable. You can use a regression spline to model the association of outcome with a continuous predictor variable, but not for the outcome by itself. It sounds like you might use a two-stage survival model, but it's hard to say without more information. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

@EdM, I have edited the question by providing more details.

Please define the experimental design.  Is treatment an endogenous or an exogenous variable, i.e., were treatment crossover times pre-determined by randomization so that treatment is exogenous and interpretation will not be complex?  If treatment is endogenous (internal time-dependent covariate) how is it chosen?

Thanks for the addition. It's still not clear to me what the "counts" outcome represents. Can a single individual have more than 1 "count" or is that just a sum over all individuals? How are "counts" evaluated over time: do you have the exact time for each "count" or just a sum over some time interval? If they are aggregated over time intervals, how many time intervals are there, and are they the same intervals for all individuals?

Response variable is uptake of healthy lifestyle intervention each month. The counts start from zero each month ie not cumulative. So if 1000 patients visited and 100 patients were recorded as being prescribed the health intervention, the count is 100 and offset for the rate is 1000

@Frank Harrell, I’m not totally sure what you mean. Each clinic had several months baseline, “active” (control sites didn’t receive during this time) and post phase in that order. E.g. 4 months baseline, followed by 15 months active, followed by 6 months post. The timeline was identical in pre specified site pairs (of which one is control). But some pairs had slightly different timeline e.g. 5, 12, 7 months respectively for the three phases

That doesn’t fully answer the design question.  Was “active” assigned by randomization?  Is this a randomized cluster crossover trial?

@Frank Harrell, active phase or any other phase was not assigned by randomization. No its not a randomized cluster crossover trial. One site pair might be in active phase whilst another in post phase at the same time.

If it wasn't randomized, how was the pairing done?  Without randomization how do you interpret the results?  How do you know there are not unmeasured differences in characteristics between the groups that explains active vs. control differences?

Pairing of clinics was performed based on set criteria e.g. size, location etc. We don’t know there aren’t unmeasured differences, hence we need to control e.g. using mean baseline as a covariate and allowing it to be flexible using a spline function.

Whilst I very much appreciate the dialogue, I’m wary that we are deviating from my original question. An approach I have since come up with is to include time as a spline term, phase as a categorical term and also their interaction. I think this will allow for the time trend to change by phase. A concern I had with this approach is that phase and time are clearly highly correlated. However, the model fits well and standard errors have not exploded.

The study involved pairs of clinics, with an initial "baseline" observation phase before interventions. Then one member of the pair had an intervention and the other served as control during the "active phase." After some period of time, the intervention was discontinued ("post phase"). Outcomes are counts of "uptake of healthy lifestyle intervention each month" per clinic.*
With a discontinuity in treatment at the switch from "active" to "post" phases, fitting the time predictor with a smooth spline might require something beyond what's in the code suggested in the question. Section 2.8 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies illustrates how to add extra knots near the discontinuity and to use the R gTrans() function in his rms package to incorporate a jump at the discontinuity and seasonal trends in a Poisson regression, similar to the scenario in this question. This web page provides more examples of how to use that function.
The problem in this case is that the duration of the "active phase" could differ among pairs of clinics. For example, some pairs of clinics had 12 months of "active phase" while others had 15.
The simplest way to deal with that would be to model the "active" and "post" phases separately. That would use all the data available for those phases, and shouldn't pose a problem with some of the clinic pairs not having values at later times within a phase. That might also simplify evaluating whether the duration of the "active" phase was associated with different trajectories of "uptake" rates during the "post" phase. One model could evaluate time relative to the "baseline" to "active" transition, while the second evaluates time relative to the "active" to the "post" transition. Each model would then be similar to an example in the linked web page, in which time was evaluated relative to time of menarche.
I haven't thought of a way to do this all together in a single model, although there might be a clever way to use gTrans() for that.

*This answer focuses on the modeling of time as raised in the question. It doesn't address Frank Harrell's concerns, noted in comments, about randomization of the intervention among members of a pair of and thus the interpretability of results.

Thanks so much @EdM,,

Thanks so much @EdM. Do you think a single time variable with time zero start of active phase, phase as a categorical predictor, and their interaction would work? Im concerned about the high correlation of phase and time though.

@user167591 I don't see a way to use a single time scale without losing information about changes at the transition from active to post phase. Say that some pairs had 12 months of active phase while others had 15. With a single time scale and an interaction with phase, at 16 months (all pairs now in post phase) you would be assuming that all pairs had the same outcomes. In fact some pairs would be 4 months post-active while others were only 1 month post-active, so you might expect differences on that account. That's why I suggest two models, centered on the transition times.

if we center on transition times, wouldn’t we get negative values extending into baseline phase? I was thinking to use mean baseline as a covariate as per the ANCOVA approach.

Also, consider your second model, with time centered on active to post transition. At e.g. time= -5 (all sites will be in active phase, 5 months prior to start of post phase). But their time relative to start active phase may differ e.g. one pair might have had active treatment for longer than another pair. Would it not be better with 2 time scales in the same model to precisely define the time since start active phase and time since start post phase for each site?

@user167591 there might be negative values of time, but that's not a problem. If you use the baseline value as a covariate you should not be using changes from baseline as the outcome. See this page. You could include the duration of the active phase as a covariate in the model for the active-to-post transition. That would implicitly "define the time since start of active phase" in a model of the time since the start of the post phase.

yes I intend the dependant variable to be  uptake rate adjusted for baseline, not change from baseline. Regarding your first model with time centred on baseline to active transition, I dont understand how one can use mean (several months) baseline as a covariate.

can you please explain the data structure (columns on which to fit model) for your first model? The way I see it, there will be columns for dependant variable, time (negative values in baseline i.e. pre active phase), baseline, plus other covariates. The dependent variable will already have values covering the baseline phase (negative time). Then, what is the use of an additional baseline covariate?

@user167591 my proposed baseline-to-active model wouldn't use an additional baseline-average covariate, as it would model changes in time directly. If the baseline values are sufficiently stable in time, you could just start analysis at the baseline-to-active transition, ignore the details of data prior to that time, and just use the prior average as a covariate. If there is substantial month-to-month variation and the transition happened at different months among pairs, however, that might lead to some problems; haven't thought that through completely.

thanks so much for your patience and explaining. Is your approach what Clyve refers to as the "pure mixed model" here: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1719532-ancova-vs-multilevel-mixed-effects-linear-regression

@user167591 yes, based on this quote from that page: "The pure mixed-effects model has both pre- and post-intervention observations for each patient and does not include the baseline outcome measurement as a covariate." That said, the choice between that modeling approach and using the average of baseline values as a covariate mostly depends on your understanding of the subject matter and how you want to explain your results to your audience.

Thank you @EdM. Could you also briefly explain why it’s not wise to model two time scales in one big model? Is it perhaps concerns about co-linearity?

@user167591 see my first comment in response to your first two comments on my answer, above. In general a single comprehensive model would make the most sense, but with different durations of active phases in your situation I couldn't figure out a way to make that work. Collinearity is often much less of a problem than it's purported to be.

I agree that the single comprehensive model would make most sense. I had in mind getting predicting expected values from such a model across the entire time period of the experiment. Am I right that with two models we can’t do this properly so that the fitted lines join up?

The mixed models you suggest seem to be equivalent to change score models, see here: https://www.middleprofessor.com/files/applied-biostatistics_bookdown/_book/models-for-longitudinal-experiments-pre-post-designs.html, sect. 19.3. This "estimates the effect as the coefficient of the interaction...[and] will give the same estimate as Model M2" (M2 is change score model). However, the above Stata page implies the mixed model is equivalent to ANCOVA ...which one is right?! Worried as @Frank Harrell appears to warn against change scores https://www.fharrell.com/post/errmed/#change-from-baseline

@user167591 I don't see a way to join up the fitted lines between the two models, given the different durations of active phase among pairs, but that might say more about me than about what's possible. ANCOVA is closely related to mixed modeling. Change scores per se aren't necessarily a problem; a paired t-test is on a change score. Problems arise if the change scores are necessarily associated with the baseline values in some way. This page has more extensive discussion.

since I plan to use splines for the time variable in each of your suggested models, I thought of presenting effects as difference in difference contrasts. Specifically, this would be (post-pre) - (post-pre) where brackets are treatment and control groups respectively. Post refers to predicted Y at several scaled times >0, and pre is predicted y = 0, the latter being constant. That way we could compute a smooth curve of double difference contrasts for the treatment effect over time. Does that sound reasonable?

sorry can I please clarify the contrasts I had in mind after fitting your suggested first model. Here time is scaled relative to baseline-active transition. I plan to present treatment effect as double differences ie y(time t) - y(time0) for treatment group minus the same for control where time t is each follow-up month and time0 is baseline. A log link means we could present such contrasts as ratio of rate ratios (RRR). Does that sound reasonable? If so, I’m still unsure about t0 for the contrasts since there are several months worth of baseline data (month 0, -1, -2, -3 etc).

Cont…my initial thought was to use Y at the single month immediately before start treatment as time0 for the contrasts. The previous baseline months (-1, -2, -3 etc) are disregarded in the contrasts; their inclusion in the model as a continuous spline is solely to get a better estimate of t0 ie the month immediately before starting treatment. The other idea I had was to use the average of all negative time points (all baseline months) as the baseline Y in the contrasts. This uses all baseline information available to us but I don’t think it works if there is a trend over baseline months?

@user167591 the choice between the last pre-treatment baseline value or an average over prior baseline values to calculate the differences is a matter of your understanding of the subject matter, not statistics. If you don't have reason (before looking at the data) to expect differences among pre-treatment values, then their average might be more precise. That probably isn't the case at the switch to the second phase of the study, however, as the prior values presumably change during the first phase. Using differences should be OK if you aren't also using baseline values as predictors.
